# How to check if a custom Control is focused?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, gui

So I am building custom UI for my MonoGame project. I've gotten pretty far already, having created Controls such as:

- Button
- Panel
- TextBox
- Form
- ComboBox
- CheckBox
- etc.

All of these controls obviously inherit from my abstract class `Control`.

This is how I check for Click on a `Control`:

```
if (Destination.Intersects(inputManager.MouseRect) && inputManager.IsMouseClicked(MouseButton.Left)) {
    Click?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    _focused = true;
}
else if (!Destination.Intersects(inputManager.MouseRect) && inputManager.IsMouseClicked(MouseButton.Left)) {
    _focused = false;
}
```

This method has gotten me pretty far already, but unfortunately it doesn't work when there are multiple `TextBox`es: each `TextBox` I click on will become focused, and any key I press will be typed in every focused `TextBox`.

Here is how I hacked around this:

- Since all Controls (including `TextBox`es) the user sees are placed in a certain `Panel`, they are in that panel's array of Controls.
- I added a `Panel _parent` to the `Control` class, thus every control would have a reference to the panel that owns it
- Then in the `Panel` class I added a `Control FocusedControl`, so that every `Panel` will have one field for its focused control

So now I'm checking like this:

```
if (_parent.FocusedControl == this)
    // This specific control is focused
```

Or like this:

```
if (_parent.FocusedControl != null)
    // There is a focused Control

if (_parent.FocusedControl == null)
    // No control is focused in this panel
```

**This works.**

But the problem is that I am doing these checks in the controls themselves, and not, for example, in the `Panel` class.

This means each control has a reference to the panel that owns it, and that panel has a list of all the controls. Also the panel's public methods and properties are available to the owned control.

This eliminates encapsulation and is effectively terrible design.

I consider this to be a huge mess and a dirty hack. Is there any other way to make sure that a `Panel` has only one focused `Control` at a time?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect method but you can try if it is better than yours.

First, you don't need to check both `Intersects` and `Click` event in one line of code. Just check `intersect` first, if the condition is true then check `Click`, if it is false, we don't need to check the second condition.

Create a list of GUI control:

```
public List<GUI_Control> controls = null;
public bool focus=false;
public GUI_Control parent=null;
```

Then check the mouse event:

```
public override bool MouseDownEventLeft(float mouse_x, float mouse_y) {
 if (!visible) return false;
 //if intersects
 if (inside(mouse_x, mouse_y)) {
  if (controls != null && controls.Count > 0) {
   // hand to my children controls
   for (int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++) {
    bool rc = controls[i].MouseDownEventLeft(mouse_x, mouse_y);
    if (rc) return true;
   }
  }
  parent.clearFocus(true);//clear focus on parent GUI
  focus = true;
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Then each time you click, only one `textbox` (or something else) is being focused (its `focused boolean` is true).